# A question on divisibility of binomial coefficient

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

In this paper, page 3, theorem 4, the author claimed that

> If $m, n, k$ are three positive integer such that $\text{gcd}(n, k)=1$ then $\binom{mn}{k}\equiv 0\pmod n$.

And he proved it as

> Let $p$
>   be an arbitrary prime divisor of $n$ with $p^a|| n$. Write $k=k_0+k_1p+k_2p^2+...k_rp^r$ in the base $p$ and note that $k_0\neq 0$ because $\text{gcd}(n, k)=1$. Since $mn=mn_0p^a$ for some $n_0$ then subtracting the base $p$ representation of $k$ from $mn$ requires at least $k$ borrows. Kummer theorem gives $\binom{mn}{k}\equiv 0\pmod {p^a}$. Since $p$ is an arbitrary divisor of $n$ we conclude that $\binom{mn}{k}\equiv 0\pmod n$.

My question is:

1- Why does he have to write $k$ in base $p$ and claim that $k_0\neq 0$.

2- How can he claim that `subtracting the base $p$ representation of $k$ from $mn$ requires at least $k$ borrows`, from  $mn=mn_0p^a$ (because it's exactly an application of the Kummer theorem?) and the above arguments ?

Please explain it to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The paper in question seems to be: Andrew D. Loveless: *A Congruence for Products of Binomial Coefﬁcients modulo a Composite*, in: [INTEGERS 7](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/vol7.html) (A44, 10 Jan 2007)

Answer (score 1):

Kummer's theorem says that the highest power of $p$ dividing ${n \choose m}$ is equal to the number of borrows when subtracting $m$ from $n$ in base $p$.

1. Since $gcd(n,k)=1$ and $p$ divides $n$, we know $p$ does not divide $k$, so in the base $p$ representation we have $k_0 \neq 0$.
2. Consider the difference of $r \times 10^a$ and a number not divisible by 10.
   Eg: 34120000-1265432. You can see that there are at least $a$ borrows for the last $a$ digits (in this example, for the last 4 digits there must be borrows).
   Similarly, the last $a$ "digits" in base $p$ are zeroes for $mn$ whereas the last $a$ digits of $k$ in base $p$ are non-zero; hence there must be at least $a$ borrows (not $k$ which might be a typo).
   Thus $p^a$ divides the binomial coefficient by Kummer's theorem.

Since this is true for each of the prime powers dividing $n$, we get that $n$ divides ${mn \choose k}$.